# Jquery Dialog does not wait for user input and server side event fired immidiatly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a `GirdView` and inside `Girdview` i have a `Checkbox` column. `Checkbox`  `AutoPostback` property is set to `TRUE` as i am doing some database work on `Checkbox` `checked` state. Now i am replacing the normal `javascript confirm` box with `Jquery` `DialogBox` BUt the problem is when user `check` the `checkbox` Dialog appears and then user have to confirm whether they are sure that they want to check the checkbox, if they press yse then checkbox is checked and then i want the server side event t fire. instead what is happening is as soon as user check the checkbox and server side event fires and then dialog appears even if they press NO, database is already updated with YES.

here is my code.

## HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
CssClass="gvClickCollectOrders" DataKeyNames="OrderId" OnRowDataBound="gvOrders_RowDataBound"
AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvOrders_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderId" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNumber" HeaderText="Order No" DataFormatString="WWW {0}"
        />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="orderDateText" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Ship Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="orderShipDateAndTrackingData" CssClass="trackingInfo"
                runat="server" Target="_blank" Text="" NavigateUrl=""></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval( "BillToFirstName") %>&nbsp;
                    <%# Eval( "BillToLastName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Received In Store">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsReceived" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# MWClickAndCollectHelper.CheckOrderReceivedStatus(AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Eval("OrderId"))) %>'
                OnCheckedChanged="cbIsReceived_CheckedChanged" CssClass="isReceivedCheckBox"
                />
                <asp:Label ID="receivedDateText" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Collected By Customer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsCollected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# MWClickAndCollectHelper.CheckOrderCollectedStatus(AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Eval("OrderId"))) %>'
                OnCheckedChanged="cbIsCollected_CheckedChanged" CssClass="isCollectedCheckBox"
                />
                <asp:Label ID="collectedDateText" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="emptyGrid" runat="server" Text="There are no 'Click and Collect' orders placed for this store."
        CssClass="emptyGridMessage"></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

## Jquery

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

var isReceivedCheckBox = $('.isReceivedCheckBox input[type=checkbox]');
var isCollectedCheckBox = $('.isCollectedCheckBox input[type=checkbox]');
var def = $.Deferred();

function confirmDialog(msg) {
    var dialog = $("<div id=\"dialog\">" + msg + "</div>");
    $(dialog).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function () {
                def.resolve();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
                'No': function () {
                def.reject();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    return def.promise();
}

$(function () {
    $(isReceivedCheckBox).on("change", function () {
        var checked = this.checked;
        var checkbox = this;
        if (checked) {
            confirmDialog("are your sure you want to check this checkbox?").done(function () {
                checkbox.checked = true;
            })
                .fail(function () {
                checkbox.checked = false;
            });
        } else {
            confirmDialog("are your sure you want to uncheck this checkbox?").done(function () {
                checkbox.checked = false;
            })
                .fail(function () {
                checkbox.checked = true;
            });
        }
    });
}); < /script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is another way but you can do postback manually.
set AutoPostBack = false and use __doPostBack function.

[www.ilearnttoday.com/tag/how-to-use-__dopostback](http://www.ilearnttoday.com/tag/how-to-use-__dopostback)

Comment: I got the basic idea of doing manual postback... +1 for the link... BUT somehow i dont understand whats wrong with my code.. and why its not working with AutoPostbask

Comment: i think they both fired same time and runs parallel. so basicly while you waiting for confirmation, postback event reaches the servers does its work. the main reason: you handle the confirmation with jquery and server side checkbox's postback action is handled by .net framework at the same time but separately.